# Block Particular Command in Linux for Specific user

Tags: linux, security, account-restrictions, restricted-shell

How to block command, let say `mkdir` for specific user ?

What I did just created read-only function and store in users profile `~/.bashrc`

```
/bin/mkdir() {
        echo "mkdir command not allow for you"

}

mkdir() {
        echo "mkdir command not allow for you"

}
./mkdir() {

        echo "mkdir command not allow for you"
}

readonly -f /bin/mkdir
readonly -f mkdir
readonly -f ./mkdir
```

**Test:**

```
rahul@ubuntu:~$ cd /bin/
rahul@ubuntu:/bin$ ./mkdir /home/rahul/ggg
mkdir command not allow for you
rahul@ubuntu:/bin$ cd
rahul@ubuntu:~$ mkdir testing
mkdir command not allow for you
rahul@ubuntu:~$ /bin/mkdir testing
mkdir command not allow for you
```

So my question is What should be the way of achieving this ?  is there any tool for this ?

Update 1 # But if user is smart , he could copy mkdir binary and rename it and use it . So how to achieve this ?

Comment: Your example will fail because the user could compile his own `mkdir` and rename it, or even just copy and rename the existing binary. Also, there's a shell builtin for overriding aliases and functions.

Comment: hmm that's correct , so is there anyway  ?

Comment: also user don't need to compile he can easily copy `cp /bin/mkdir mkdir2` then use it :(

Comment: Creating a directory is such a common/fundamental task that there are multiple ways of doing it, and it would be almost impossible to block them all (except by not letting the user create files; i.e., write-protecting all directories against him).  For example, `cp -r /usr/local/lib ggg` will create a directory called `ggg` (containing a copy of the contents of `/usr/local/lib`, if any, which the user can then just delete).  You can use `find / -type d -empty` to find an empty directory to copy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with bash, but I know of another shell that restricts the user environment: [lshell (limited shell)](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell).

**A quick overview of configuration**

Lshell is configured via an INI file. By default, it holds a whitelist of allowed commands, but it can be easily configured to prohibit user from using a specific command.

This configuration (default conf `/etc/lshell.conf`) prohibits user `foo` from using `mkdir`:

```
[foo]
allowed = 'all' - ['mkdir', 'bash', 'sh', 'csh', 'dash', 'env']
```

In order to configure a user account to use lshell by default, you must:

```
 chsh -s /usr/bin/lshell foo
```

Lshell can do more, like:

- 3 levels of granularity: user, group, all.
- Can restrict access to certain paths in the system.
- Can restrict the use of certain characters (like `|`).
- Can restrict the use of certain commands only over SSH.

And more.

**Update 1#** Added Test Result :

```
rahul:~$ which bash
/bin/bash
rahul:~$ dd if=$(which bash) of=my_bash
*** forbidden syntax: dd if=$(which bash) of=my_bash
rahul:~$ bash
*** forbidden command: bash
rahul:~$ cp /bin/bash my_bash
*** forbidden path: /bin/bash
rahul:~$ /bin/bash
*** forbidden command: /bin/bash
rahul:~$ sh
*** forbidden command: sh
rahul:~$ dash
*** forbidden command: dash
rahul:~$ env bash
*** forbidden command: env
rahul:~$ cp /bin/mkdir mycreatedir
*** forbidden path: /bin/mkdir
```

Comment: with `allowed = 'all' - ['mkdir']`, can't you just execute `bash` and be unrestricted again?

Comment: @dawud you are correct, so I had modified entry to `allowed = 'all' - ['mkdir', 'bash', 'sh', 'csh', 'dash', 'env']`

Comment: Just being pedantic, sorry, but there are still a lot of ways to circumvent the restrictions imposed by that list, e.g. `dd if=$(which bash) of=my_bash && chmod u+x my_bash && ./my_bash`. I think the problem is the lack of a restrictive default policy, i.e., in this scenario you GRANT permissions by default, then DENY permissions based on a list, when it should be the other way around: DENY by default, then GRANT based on policy.

Comment: @dawud: I agree that maintaining a whitelist of allowed commands is a better approach than having a blacklist and hoping the user won't circumvent it by out-clevering the admin.

Comment: What is the difference of using a whitelist? You can still copy `bash` to `ls` and launch your shell as `ls`, or any other whitelisted command for that matter.

Comment: @Marco, check the example provided in my answer. I provide a whitelist of allowed commands, and in that scenario, the user cannot just `cp` a binary to his/her PATH (`root` owned directory, `rx` for the user), and `rbash` prevents from executing `./executables`. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @dawud It does, indeed. I missed the read-only bin directory.

Comment: @Marco and dawud I have added tested scenario

Comment: Thanks! I have created a user with basic permissions & commands available using this on my old netbook (now network attached storage) , so i can use [ssh button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pd7l.sshbutton&hl=en) on my phone in case of security flaws.

Answer (score 15):

The way I usually implement this kind of restrictions requires that several conditions are met, otherwise the restriction can be easily circumvented:

- The user does not belong to the `wheel` group, the only one authorized to use `su` (enforced via PAM).
- The user is given a properly secured `rbash` with a read-only PATH pointing to a private `~/bin`, this `~/bin/` directory contains links to simple utilities:

  ```
  $ ll ~/bin
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 14 Sep 17 08:58 clear -> /usr/bin/clear*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  7 Sep 17 08:58 df -> /bin/df*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 egrep -> /bin/egrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  8 Sep 17 08:58 env -> /bin/env*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 fgrep -> /bin/fgrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  9 Sep 17 08:58 grep -> /bin/grep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 rview -> /bin/rview*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 rvim -> /usr/bin/rvim*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 sudo -> /usr/bin/sudo*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 17 Sep 17 08:58 sudoedit -> /usr/bin/sudoedit*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 tail -> /usr/bin/tail*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 11 Sep 17 08:58 wc -> /usr/bin/wc*
  ```
- the user is given a restricted, read-only environment (think of stuff like `LESSSECURE`, `TMOUT`, `HISTFILE` variables).
- the user is mapped to the SELinux user `staff_u` and given rights to execute commands as other user as required via `sudo`.
- the user's `/home`, `/tmp` and possibly `/var/tmp` are polyinstantiated via `/etc/security/namespace.conf`:

  ```
  /tmp       /tmp/.inst/tmp.inst-$USER-     tmpdir:create   root
  /var/tmp   /tmp/.inst/var-tmp.inst-$USER- tmpdir:create   root
  $HOME      $HOME/$USER.inst/              tmpdir:create   root
  ```

  Also, `/etc/security/namespace.init` makes all skeletal files readonly for the user and owned by `root`.

This way you can choose whether `$USER` can execute `mkdir` on his/her own behalf (via a link in the private `~/bin` directory, provisioned via `/etc/skel`, as explained above), on behalf of other user (via `sudo`) or none at all.

Answer (score 4):

Add a dummy group, add the user to that group, `chown root:somegroup /bin/mkdir`, `chmod g-x /bin/mkdir`. Note that this relies on the user not being able to modify their groups. IIRC this is true in GNU/Linux but not in some other Unices.

Comment: On most filesystems you can also use extended ACLs for finer grained control - the number of groups needed would grow exponentially with the number of users (due to possible combinations), not to mention the naming problems.

Comment: add one more point, also remove read permission from other users 710, so user could not copy and rename that binary isn't it ?

Comment: @RahulPatil yes, and of course you need to restrict their use of a compiler as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best as i have tested is to use Profile.d best & safest way

#### Step # 1 (Create a Alias File)

```
[root@newrbe ~]# vim /etc/customalias.sh
```

Add Below lines :

```
alias rm="echo remove contenet is restricted"
alias poweroff="echo Poweroff is restricted"
alias chmod="echo Change Permission is restristed"
```

Save & quit

#### Step # 2 (Create Profile loader)

/etc/profile.d/ this location contains files for bash completion

```
[root@newrbe ~]# vim /etc/profile.d/customsource.sh
```

Add below lines under the files these lines will block mentioned commands for below users

```
if [ `whoami` == "user1" ] && [ `whoami` == "user2" ]; then
    source /etc/customalias.sh
fi
```

save and quit

Now Exit and relogin

Regards,
-Mansur

Comment: `/etc/profile.d/` is not for _`bash` completion_, it's where to place login session customisations for users using POSIX-like login shells, so it's typically not where `bash` alias customisations (which would rather go in `/etc/bash.bashrc`) would go and it should have a POSIX shell syntax (so typically, `.` instead of `source` and `=` instead of `==`).

Answer (score -1):

install sudoers and try to configure there whose users and what command.

Comment: Welcome to SX. Please add details to your answer; the OP, or anyone else reading this question in the future, may not be aware of `sudo`.

Comment: This answer is just plainly wrong