# Setting group permission on directory

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I'm looking for the best way to give a group permission to view any files in /var/log, but only using cat or tail. My best guess right now is that I need to use ACL's:

```
 setfacl -mR default:g:group:4 /var/log
```

Not sure how to limit them only to using cat or tail. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: take look at this thread.. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90998/block-particular-command-in-linux-for-specific-user

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. I am also reading up on visudo and possibly going to use command alias. It looks like it will probably satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than muck with the permissions of `/var/log` I think I'd go the direction of giving these users `sudo` rights for a limited set of commands.

#### Setting up sudo access

You can create a command alias in the `/etc/sudoers` files like so:

```
Cmnd_Alias RDONLY_VARLOG = tail /var/log/messages, tail /var/log/maillog, ...
```

Then grant users access to this command alias, again in the `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
# single user
user1    ALL = RDONLY_VARLOG

# group of users (group1)
%group1  ALL = RDONLY_VARLOG
```