# How do you give a developer group access to apache, MySQL, php and the webroot?

Tags: users, rsync, mysql, group, apache-httpd

We have 3 web designers that are currently logging in to our server via root to configure apache and setup websites.

I have very basic linux knowledge (I'm a web designer) and have created users and groups via Webmin - but how do you give the group access to:

- Apache (/etc/apache2/)
- MySQL
- PHP
- SSH (rsync etc)
- The webroot

They need to be able to transfer files via rsync, upload and dump databases and setup virtual hosts etc.

Incase it makes a difference, Virtualmin is also installed on this server - which is a Debain 7 server.

I'm obviously using the wrong search terms as I can't find easy, basic info so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would never use `webmin`, `virtualmin` or any so-called "control panel" for any serious task.

The majority of the tasks you enumerate do not need direct access to the managed host:

- the contents under the webroot should be managed using any of the many [version control managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software) out there, my choice would be `git`. Set up a `hub` and a `live` repositories as described [here](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/).
- setup a chrooted `vsftp` server to provide access to directly upload content to an area outside the repository.
- you can use the `hub`-`live` schema to manage the `apache` configuration. You could even configure hooks to test the correctness of the configuration files and gracefully restart the server. Another alternative is to provide [limited access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90998/block-particular-command-in-linux-for-specific-user/91003#91003) to the developers to run specific commands using `sudo`.
- MySQL can be accessed remotely if configured securely, or you can use the method linked above to provide access via `sudo`.

Comment: No worries, your post is a bit out of our league sorry - hence trying to use webmin. It's a shame good security practices aren't easier to implement but I understand that it's probably a complex subject - thanks for your suggestions though. Cheers