# Restrict bash command for specific user

Tags: bash, ssh

I just searched on this [page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90998/block-particular-command-in-linux-for-specific-user), but the answer does not meet my idea. My idea is when user called Bob access ssh and run a command, for example `sudo apt-get update`, then the bash sheell will respond with `sudo: command not found`. How to make this happen instead of using lsh (limited shell)?

Comment: Why do you want to have it respond `sudo: command not found`. Do you want to control access to privileged operations? If so then you should just configure `sudo` (with `visudo`) to allow/deny it as appropriate. Otherwise you can play games with different users' `$PATH` so that some commands are absent from the `$PATH` for certain users but not others, but then they can always call the commands directly with full pathnames or install their own versions.

Comment: In short, [what are you really trying to achieve here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are talking about a chroot environment, when a user or group meets some usage restrictions by having only specific binaries and configs in their directory root level. It is possible to configure `sshd` to do that.
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` options:

```
Match user john
          ChrootDirectory /var/john/
```

Put /bin, /etc, /sbin, /usr and other required elements to their chroot directories and here you are.

Take a look at [this](http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access) article, it may help as well.